# Passing data from recylerview adapter to fragments in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-intent, adapter, android-recyclerview

I want to pass data from recycleview Adapter to a fragment and then open the fragment. I tried things mentioned but its not working. Should I implement fragment to fragment or activity to fragment? Please provide a solution. How do I do it?

```
public class QuotationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuotationAdapter.ViewHolder>implements Filterable {
private Context context;
String id;
private List<ListQuotation> contactList;
private List<ListQuotation> contactListFiltered;
private QuotationAdapter.ContactsAdapterListener listener;
 Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final QuotationAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ListQuotation contact = contactListFiltered.get(position);
    holder.item_list_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            context = v.getContext();
            id = contact.getId();
           passData(id);

        }
    });

 }

private void passData(String id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,QuotationItemDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", ""+id);
   context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

**This is my fragment**

```
public class ItemListFragment extends Fragment {
String id;
TableLayout tv;
private static final String url = "";
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //returning our layout file
    //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
    final View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);

    tv = (TableLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tableexp);
    loadItemData();

    //get id
    id = getArguments().getString("id");
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: since you are passing your data through intent. First get your data inside your activity using getIntent().getExtra() & when adding your fragment, set the data which you got earlier inside the bundle and use setArguments over fragment object and get Inside fragment using getArguments().getString("id")

Comment: @Gautam - yes thanks